# How to convert image buffer to form-data in node.js?

Tags: node.js, buffer, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a buffer of an image like:

```
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 04 03 03 03 03 02 04 03 03 03 04 04 04 05 06 0a 06 06 05 05 06 0c 08 09 07 ... 231835 more bytes>
```

and I have installed form-data module from npm.

I need to send this image file as form-data, I tried:

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append("image", buffer, { filename: "london.jpg" });
```

But it didn't work, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could try [form-auto-content](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-auto-content)

Comment: you want to send file from your node app to somwhere? or u want to receive that app in your node app?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty sir, I want to send this buffer to another server(written in Python I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to resolve the issue by using request module.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
request.post({
    url,
    formData: {
        image: {
            value: file.buffer, // Give your node.js buffer to here
            options: {
                filename: file.originalname, // filename
                contentType: file.mimetype // file content-type
            }
        }
    }
},(error, http_response, body) => {

});
```

Comment: I would not recommend using request, it has been deprecated..

Comment: @eol Cannot find any other solution unfortunatelly..